# Correct way to use BibTeX in beamer

Tags: beamer, bibliographies, bibtex

Should I make any changes in the way I include bibliography when I move from `article`/`report` to `beamer`? (For example, do I need to include basic `bst` files?)

When I use BibTeX in `beamer`, I always get

> Undefined control sequence `\citename`

errors.

What is the proper way to get rid of this? I would prefer not to move to BibLaTeX for this reason (though may be I will try BibLaTeX after some time).

Here is an MWE:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\cite{west}
\bibliographystyle{authordate1}
\bibliography{sampleBib}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

I am pretty sure the `bib` file is proper. Included here for convenience.

```
@book{west,
title={Introduction to Graph Theory},
author={West, D.},
isbn={9780131437371},
lccn={2016055247},
series={Math Classics},
year={2017},
publisher={Pearson}
}
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are three issues here. One is that you need

```
\usepackage{authordate1-4}
```

in order to use the `authordate1` bibliography style. However, the necessary file, `authordate1-4.sty` is missing from my machine (which has a full TeXLive installation). It might be missing from yours as well; you can [download it from CTAN](http://anorien.csc.warwick.ac.uk/mirrors/CTAN/biblio/bibtex/contrib/authordate/authordate1-4.sty) and place it in the same folder as your presentation. My guess is that it has been forgotten; the last update to [authordate](https://ctan.org/tex-archive/biblio/bibtex/contrib/authordate) seems to have taken place in 1992, and other packages that provide similar functionality (e.g. [harvard](https://ctan.org/pkg/harvard)) are probably used in its place.

The third issue is that beamer doesn't work well with BibTeX. Indeed, section 10.6 of the [beamer package documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/beamer/doc/beameruserguide.pdf) suggests that you should use BibTeX to generate a `.bbl` file, copy the contents of this into a frame, and manually edit the bibliography to achieve the formatting you need.

However,  with the `\usepackage{authordate1-4}` command, and the `authordate1-4.sty` file downloaded, your example does compile for me.

Comment: But, this changed the look of the bibliography and citations. The latter worries me more. Instead of the typical square brackets, parentheses are used now in citations.